# jQuery: navigate to another page by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement

I'm learning JavaScript and jQuery. I'm trying to build a simple web page with buttons that navigate to another page upon click via a switch-case statement.

I've added a local jQuery script to my .html file, but nothing seems to happen when I click the buttons.

Demo can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/VmYLy/

The html code is:

```
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
     switch(this.id) {
         case 'x':
             window.location.href = "http://google.com"; 
             break;
         case 'y': 
             window.location.href = "http://yahoo.com"; 
             break;
         case 'z': 
             window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; 
             break;
            }
        });    
</head>

<body>        
    <input type="button" value="google" style="width:120px" id="x"><br>
    <input type="button" value="yahoo" style="width:120px" id="y"><br>
    <input type="button" value="stackoverflow" style="width:120px" id="z"><br>
</body>
```

Comment: have you actually tried this in your machine or just in jsfiddle? I'm afraid you can't redirect in jsfiddle

Comment: it seems to be working fine, fiddle trows error `Refused to display 'http://stackoverflow.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Comment: of course i've tried this on my machine. nothing happens :/
how can i be sure the jquery library is loaded correctly to the browser?

Comment: it doesn't work in jsfiddle but when you look in your console you find this: Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8X8tU5uSGMmK8Qeg7YCgDg does not permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: What's wrong with using plain old `<a href=...>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine in fiddle. only prob i can think of is to wrap your code in `ready()`. This might not be causing problem in fiddle since you've selected `onLoad` option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
        switch(this.id) {
            case 'x':window.location.href = "http://google.com"; break;
            case 'y': window.location.href="http://yahoo.com"; break;
            case 'z': window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; break;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: it works! thanks! could you please elaborate why do i need to wrap my code in a ready statement?

Comment: @AlexTal you need to make sure that te script is executed after the buttons are created, if the script execute before that obviously it won't work.. :) http://api.jquery.com/ready/